# Sessions with(no) cookies

Tags: session, web-applications, web

For a web application I could figure no session cookies stored . There was a string as

> SSLJSESSION=0000SESSIONMANAGEMENTAFFINI:-1

From my understanding , this cannot be used to handle sessions , Still the application is handling the sessions properly .

Can anyone please tell me how session handling is done with the above technique ?

Comment: this is actually without cookies according to me , still it handles session .. May be a proper with(out) would suffice .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of browsing through WebSphere’s documentation, I found out that WebSphere (actually IBM HTTP Server as well as SUN One Web Server) support a feature called SSL ID Session Tracking. Basically, what this does is bind web application sessions to SSL sessions. This further does not require the web application to do almost any session handling since the server performs this on behalf of the application.